# How to overload operator<< with a reference pointer on the RHS?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand how to correctly overload the operator << with a pointer variable on the RHS, **using a reference parameter**.  Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
 public:
   void print(ostream& out) const { out << "Hello World!"; }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A*& handle)
{
   handle->print(out);
   return out;
}

int main() {
   A *a = new A();
   cout << a << endl;
   delete a;
}
```

I am assuming that the result should be `Hello World!`.  Instead, the program prints the address of the object `a` `0x7f9bc6405be0`, so apparently `cout << a` is not calling my overloading function.

Could anyone please explain why my definition of overloading << is not working as I expected?

Comment: Your function is not the best match because the parameter is `const`, while your variable `a` is not.  Make them match.

Comment: It may help your responses to explain _exactly why_ you are passing that pointer by reference.  Your code, as written, doesn't need that parameter to be a reference and doesn't work because it's a reference.

Comment: Change `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A*& handle)` to `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A* handle)` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Yes, there's no point using a reference for a primitive (small) type like a pointer, which is more efficiently passed by value.

Comment: i'd rather suggest you to drop the pointer and instead call `cout << *a << endl;`. Overloading operators for pointers isnt that common, ie it is a surprise and surprises arent nice

Comment: "Isn't that common" is putting it lightly. In a large codebase, this is the kind of thing that would make someone scream after debugging strange behaviour for an hour.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, only overload operators where one argument is an object of class type that you wrote. (And put the overloads in the same namespace as your class definition). Otherwise, nasty gremlins await.

Comment: @PaulSanders @Eljay I understand your suggestions.  I just want to understand the syntax of `const type& identifier` for a parameter better.  @DrewDormann your first comment works in the sense that I change the line `A *a = new A();` to `const A *a = new A();`.  What I don't understand is if `type` above is not a pointer, why I can still pass a non-`const` variable in and the call still matches the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that -- in the spirit of similar overloaded functions -- you were trying to make your parameter a **const reference**.  That is, a reference to a const object.

Your parameter:

```
 const A*& handle
```

Is **not** a const reference.  It's a (reference `&`) to a (mutable pointer `*`) to a (`const A`).

Change your parameter to this and it will work:

```
 A *const & handle
```

This is a (reference `&`) to a (const pointer `*const`) to an (`A`).

Whether `A` is const or not is up to you and the intentions of your code.

See it working in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7eoY4M7Ya).

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for!  I didn't know that pointer operator `*` can be modified by `const` this way.  I was indeed confused by how to make my parameter a const reference.  Thanks.

Comment: @C.-C.Yang a pointer is a _type_ (not an operator) and any type can be const. Look into "east const" if you would like to develop a habit of confidently putting `const` in the right spot.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry.  `*` is a type when used in a declaration.  I will look into "east const".  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
 public:
   void print(ostream& out) const { out << "Hello World!"; }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A*& handle)
{
   handle->print(out);
   return out;
}

int main() {
   A *a = new A();
   cout << a << endl;
   delete a;
}
```

operator<< function expects reference to pointer of A object in your code. You may use ref to pointer function, for example, to change the address of the parameter because if you call the function by sending pointer and expecting pointer as in the below then the function copies the address of the object to that pointer points to use in its stack and loses the address of the pointer, so the function cannot change the address of the parameter.

You can change the signature in two ways like those, then it works:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A* handle)
```

Here, the caller calls the function with pass by value of A*, then inside the function it accesses the print function.

Second way about which also your other question is, to correct the mismatch by adding const keyword to the variable within main function or deleting const keyword in the signature of the function. Converting a non-const pointer to const reference to pointer implicitly may yield an invalid state:

```
int* p;
const int x;
// a now reference to pointer p; it is not valid operation sure
const int*& a = p;  
// if this operation was allowed and if we also changed the address
// to that p points 
*a = &x;
// then it would allow p to access and change const so we would change const data through non-cont pointer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments so far, I did some more experiments.  It all boils down to the match between a call and a function signature.  The following code demonstrates this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void test(int& a) { // I can remove this function.
   cout << "void test(int& a): a = "
        << a << endl;
}

void test(const int& a) {
   cout << "void test(const int& a): a = "
        << a << endl;
}

void test(int*& a) { // I cannot remove this function.
   cout << "void test(int*& a): a = "
        << *a << endl;
}

void test(const int*& a) {
   cout << "void test(const int*& a): a = "
        << *a << endl;
   a = a + 3;
}

int main() {
   int a = 2, c = 5;
   const int b = 3, d = 7;
   int* pc = &c;
   const int* pd = &d;
   test(a);
   test(b);
   test(pc);
   test(pd);
}
```

The code prints

```
void test(int& a): a = 2
void test(const int& a): a = 3
void test(int*& a): a = 5
void test(const int*& a): a = 7
```

Curiously, I can remove the function `void test(int& a)` and the call `test(a)` will use the function `void test(const int& a)`.  By contrast, I cannot remove the function `void test(int*& a)` and the call `test(pc)` will still not match the function `void test(const int*& a)`.

If someone can explain this difference in the comments, I can mark this question as answered.

Comment: please do not use answers for follow up questions. You can always open a new question t to ask more questions.